# Write my Literature Review

Tags: thesis

I started my dissertation and I want some advices in how to start the literature review. I know that it should be systematic and not a simple summary of each book or article. But my doubts relate to citations, i.e. not how to include them, but if I should start from the most recent work to the odelst. Second, if I should use Word for citations or  other softwares.

Comment: Universities often have dissertation guidelines or even templates for this sort of question. Ask locally.

Comment: The answer will likely be particular to your field, your topic, and your needs. At minimum, the literature review will establish that existing work in the field supports your work but does not duplicate it (i.e., it provides reasons why your dissertation is worthwhile.)